# Getting smaller list through this weird operation in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have `list1` and a factor called `n`. Now, I do this weird operation to return `list2` from `list1` based on the factor `n` (>1). Here is an example:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
n=2
list2=[3,7,11,15,19]
```

Notice that `list2` is obtained by summing the adjacent numbers.Another example is :

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
n=2.5
list2=[4.5,10.5,17,23]
```

In this case: `n`=2.5. So the first element in `list2` = `list1[0]+list1[1]+0.5*list1[2]` and the second element is `0.5*list1[2]+list1[3]+list1[4]` and so on. The `len(list2)=ceil(len(list1)/n)`

I can do it for n=2,4,8 etc. by recursively applying the following function I wrote.

```
def (list1,n):
list2len=ceil(len(list1)/n)
      tmparr=np.empty(list2len,dtype=float)
      for i in range(0, list2len) :
         j=2*i
         tmparr[i]=Filter[j]+Filter[j+1]
      list2=np.empty(list2len,dtype=float)
      np.copyto(list2,tmparr)
```

But, I am not sure how to code this in python for n ~= 2^m. Any help?

Comment: Which cases should we use the variable "n"?

Comment: "Any help" -> [God helps those who help themselves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_helps_those_who_help_themselves). In other words, try before, and ask for help if you did not manage to do it.

Comment: @Rightleg : I could get the integer `n` working

Comment: @leaf n is a decimal (>1). It won't be any arbitrary number, but it can have upto two decimal places. say multiples of 0.05 starting from 1.05

Answer (score 4):

This is one way:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
n = 2.5

list2 = []
s = 0
f = n
for x in list1:
    s += x*min(f, 1.)
    f -= 1
    if f <= 0:
        list2.append(s)
        s = x*-f
        f += n
print list2
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you